# Fatal Exception: Thread-3 on Android box

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

Im using an old code for a audio playlist player.  I have it working on all the emulators and have tried it on my phone with Android 8.1.0.  The device having problems is a Android box running 7.1.2 (rooted).  Im not smart enough to figure out what the problem is, please help.

From what I can see, the app crashes only on this android box with this Nougat Android.  It crashes when the called song has a PNG file as the mp3 metadata album image.  I dont know if its a problem with the PNG format, or if the size is too big for this Android device.  The average mp3 album cover in jpg is 70kb, but most of these PNG files are around 500kb.  Could this be overwhelming the memory or something???  Is that why the emulators or my new phone dont crash?

The debugging shows this error:

    `D/MainActivity: media start
    D/MainActivity: just loaded: /storage/emulated/0/Music
    D/MainActivity: path :/storage/emulated/0/Music
    D/MainActivity: proper: 3, other: 0; 3
    D/MainActivity: player, permissions: true
    D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
    D/MainActivity: AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED
    D/MainActivity: onCreate: ends
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
        Process: com.mk.music, PID: 7511
        java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFED
            at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:69)
            at com.mk.music.entity.Track.<init>(Track.java:35)
            at com.mk.music.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:236)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)`

Track.java:35 is this command,

```
        34     public Track(File file, MediaMetadataRetriever mmr) {
        35     mmr.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

MainActivity.java:236 is this,

```
            233     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            234     public void run() {
            236             for(File file : properFiles) {
            237                 Track tempTrack = new Track(file, mmr);
            238                 allTracks.add(tempTrack);
            239                 playList.add(allTracks.indexOf(tempTrack));
                    }
```